How can i bypass immobiliser on Nissan k12
I have problem with Nissan k12 it was left for about 2 years now it's not starting when i turn on ignition all lights turn on the chip light remain on the engine is not starting I check all fuse

Fuses are dead last on my list of things to check when starting up a sitting vehicle that is dead. Was it left indoors or outdoors?

I missed the title of this post. You mention an immobilizer. How have you deduced that the immobilizer is the reason the car won't start? Do you not have the transponder on your FOB? Is the FOB battery dead? Replace it according to specs...

A flat battery is your most likely culprit - charge it. When you do, check the terminal connectors that they're free of corrosion, and check the voltage after you've tended it.
Bad fuel is next most likely culprit. Bad fuel can clog injectors, filters, and rails. A very characteristic bad fuel scenario is that the vehicle only slightly turns over, then quickly dies, it also smells like vinegar.
You may also need to lubricate the pistons. And consider why the car sat for 2 years, something may have already been shot at that point, such as a bad starter solenoid, and the prior owner gave up.
Various other things may have corroded, and even once you get it running, you need to check about 50 other things before it's really safe to drive.
